# Manually styling separator within context menu to have same style as my XAML version. WPF

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I have a context menu open up when I right click on a line I have rendered within WPF. I wanted to increase the leeway allowed to the user for right clicking, so manually checked my lines for their coordinates to check against the right click position, and if we get a hit, open up a context menu that should be exactly the same as if they had right clicked exactly on the line.

The functionality works, however, my two context menus are slightly different. Here's the direct hit context menu:

[image]

And the XAML for this context menu:

```
<Line.ContextMenu>
                                        <ContextMenu>
                                            <Separator>
                                                <Separator.Template>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Separator">
                                                        <StackPanel>
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                                            <Separator/>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Separator.Template>
                                            </Separator>
                                            <MenuItem Header="Normal" Command="{Binding SetNormalCommand}"></MenuItem>
                                            <MenuItem Header="Reverse" Command="{Binding SetReverseCommand}"></MenuItem>
                                        </ContextMenu>
                                    </Line.ContextMenu>
```

Here's the context menu when you miss the line but are within the leeway area:

[image]

And the manual code I made for this context menu:

```
if (CheckArea(point.NormalLine, clickX, clickY) || CheckArea(point.ReverseLine, clickX, clickY)) {
                        MenuItem header = new MenuItem{ Header = point.Name};
                        MenuItem norm = new MenuItem { Header ="Normal"};
                        MenuItem reverse = new MenuItem { Header ="Reverse"};
                        Separator sep = new Separator {  };

                        norm.Command = point.SetNormalCommand;
                        reverse.Command = point.SetReverseCommand;

                        contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                        contextMenu.Items.Add(header);
                        contextMenu.Items.Add(sep);
                        contextMenu.Items.Add(norm);
                        contextMenu.Items.Add(reverse);


                        contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
                        _window.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
                        break;

                    }                    
                    else {
                        contextMenu.IsOpen = false;
                        _window.ContextMenu = null;
                    }
```

Is there any code I can add to my manual version that will get me the same style? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I should mention the 'header' for the context menu on a direct hit is non clickable, whereas the one for the area is clickable, which is another difference.

Comment: If you add a key on your ContextMenu then you can get it from code behind, by look in resources of said line, and then just apply that to the leeway area.

Comment: Could you maybe show me some XAML code so I can get an idea of what you mean please? Is it essentially adding a converter so I can inspect the properties of the Context Menu? @XAMlMAX

Answer (score 0):

In your C# code you are creating a `MenuItem` for the Name property but in your XAML code you have defined a `DataTemplate` for your `Seperator` where you have binded the Name property. That is why you are getting the difference in the `ContextMenu`. So in your code behind also you need to define `DataTemplate` for your `Seperator` instead of a new `MenuItem` for the Name property. You can do it as following

```
if (CheckArea(point.NormalLine, clickX, clickY) || CheckArea(point.ReverseLine, clickX, clickY)) 
{
                    MenuItem norm = new MenuItem { Header ="Normal"};
                    MenuItem reverse = new MenuItem { Header ="Reverse"};
                    Separator sep = new Separator();

                    ControlTemplate dt = new ControlTemplate();
                    FrameworkElementFactory stackPanelElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
                    dt.VisualTree = stackPanelElement;

                    FrameworkElementFactory txtElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Textblock));
                    txtElement.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, point.Name);
                    stackPanelElement.AppendChild(txtElement);

                    FrameworkElementFactory seperatorElement = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Seperator));
                    stackPanelElement.AppendChild(seperatorElement);

                    sep.Template = dt;

                    norm.Command = point.SetNormalCommand;
                    reverse.Command = point.SetReverseCommand;

                    contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
                    contextMenu.Items.Add(sep);
                    contextMenu.Items.Add(norm);
                    contextMenu.Items.Add(reverse);

                    contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
                    _window.ContextMenu = contextMenu;
                    break;

                }                    
                else 
                {
                    contextMenu.IsOpen = false;
                    _window.ContextMenu = null;
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! `txtElement.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, point.Name);` gives me the error 'cannot convert from 'string' to System.Windows.Data.Binding.BindingBase'. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try the updated answer. Just removed the Binding and assigned the Text property directly.

Comment: 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
'PN719B' text cannot be added because text is not valid in this element.'

(PN719B is the point name in this instance)

Comment: You can try it now

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml Line.Resources tag you would have your context menu like this:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
    <Separator>
        <Separator.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Separator">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    <Separator/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Separator.Template>
    </Separator>
    <MenuItem Header="Normal" Command="{Binding SetNormalCommand}"></MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Reverse" Command="{Binding SetReverseCommand}"></MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Once you have that you can assign it to a Line like this:

```
<Line Name="ContextLine" ContextMenu="{DynamicResource ContextMenu}"/>
```

Then in your code behind, you would do this:

```
var ctx = this.ContextLine.TryFindResource("ContextMenu") as ContextMenu;
_window.ContextMenu = ctx;
```

This way you are acquiring the same `ContextMenu` from Xaml and just appling it through code.

Comment: I'm applying MVVM practices so have no code behind for my XAML. Do you know a work around for this? EDIT: I tried doing `_window.TryFindResource("ContextMenu") as ContextMenu;` instead as a workaround, but it didn't work

Comment: If you are doing MvvM what is _window doing in your view model?! __No__ UI elements inside of the view model are allowed!

Comment: True, but this is simply for testing purposes! Bottom line is I don't have any code behind in my XAML files though, I just passed _window into my View Model Constructor to try something :)

Comment: If you want to achieve this without code behind then don't do it in C# at all. Alternative would be to have this as a service, but you would also need to have code behind to call that service. This answer is based on that you are doing this in code behind. Having code behind to deal with UI is absolutely fine, you can even call VM from there and it is also fine. But never have anything to do with UI in your View Model! That includes `ContextMenu`, `MenuItem`, `Separator`, `FrameworkElementFactory` etc ...